# Refresh or Direct Url not working after bundle with webpack in react js?

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, webpack, routes, react-router

I had an issue that the react js app with browser history only working on normal. But after build with webpack, i had an issue with refresh or paste relative url. If i'm using hash history instead of browser history it works well. I used several methods, but i'm only getting the issue [image]

Mostly says this is a problem of tomcat server not webpack; If any one know to solve this issue please give a valid answers.

Note: I don't wanna use hash history, it's ugly for urls

Answer (score 0):

You should only use **browser history** if you have a backend server supporting your application with routes.

If you're using webpack-dev-server (or any other) on a fully client side app you should use **hash history**

If you're using react-router v4 they are both accessible by **BrowserRouter** and **HashRouter** components.

Comment: Thanks @lokuzt. Its a known one. I want to have a browser history working for refresh even after webpack-build on client side,Is there any option for this?

Comment: @PraveenKumarS you must run some server Node or whatever that redirects every route to your generated html file.

Comment: Yes you are correct, but routing is not a problem. Refresh or page redirect by url alone not working on this case?

Comment: @PraveenKumarS I know. because webpack-dev-server does not have routes for that. For actual browser routing to work your server must have correct route handling.

Comment: Thanks @lokuzt. What kind of solution we have for this now?

Comment: @PraveenKumarS If you don't mind havinga SPA like hash history I would say keep the hash history because it works. If you're not building an SPA then find a backend stack that you like and setup every route to go to your generated html

Comment: hash url is not a recommended way for SEO.That is the only reason behind this analysis @lokuzt

Comment: @PraveenKumarS if you need SEO you must investigate Server SIde Rendering. Look at projects like Next.js and After.js they both provide SSR project support in React and that way you get SEO

Comment: Thanks @lokuzt. I think i had a solution in the past let me try once.

Comment: I done it with nginx with adding little redirecting.Anyway thank you so much @lokuzt